# Parse vector elements as string in R

Tags: r, string, vector

I know this is simple, but I cannot find a straightforward solution.

How can I tell the interpreter to read vector contents as string without using quotation marks?
Example:

```
vector<-c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH")
vector
[1] "AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD" "EEE" "FFF" "GGG" "HHH"
```

What if I want to build the same object with:

```
vector<-c(AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH)
Error: object 'AAA' not found
```

Do we have some function like "to.character" or something? It would help me much. Thanks in advance, sorry for naive question.

Comment: Another possible method to consider is to use `span`. For example, `scan(textConnection("AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH"), what="", sep=",")` or exclude the sep argument if these are separated by white space.

Comment: @Imo I think your suggestion is good, why not make it an answer as an extension to the suggestion of @SeGa? thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without quotes, `AAA` etc will be interpreted as names and an object with this name will be sought for. So you will need nonstandard evaluation (using the argument "as is", without evaluating -- `substitute` returns the unevaluated expression, and `deparse` converts it to a string), something like

```
c__ <- function(...) sapply(substitute(list(...)),deparse)[-1]
vec <-c__(AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH)
vec 
# [1] "AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD" "EEE" "FFF" "GGG" "HHH"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This is genius, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

You're not trying to coerce anything to character here. You're trying to input a string literal without telling R that it's a string literal. You can coerce another kind of vector to a character vector with `as.character()`, e.g., `as.character(1:10)`, but there's nothing you can do that will allow R to interpret `AAA` as `"AAA"`.  The interpreter will always look for an object named `AAA`, if you tell use `AAA` instead of `"AAA"`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!.. I will try to make the best of this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can do that, as R will look for the object AAA which will not be found. But why not just put quotes around the whole thing and then split the vector by ","?

```
vector<-"AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH"

vec <- strsplit(vector, ",")[[1]]

str(vec)
 chr [1:8] "AAA" " BBB" " CCC" " DDD" " EEE" " FFF" " GGG" " HHH"
```

Answer (score 2):

As one learns R, it's important to think about the relationship between a vector and a data frame. A data frame can be thought of as a collection of related vectors of a given length. Therefore, another solution to this problem using Base R is to use one of the file read functions (e.g. `read.table()`) and extract the vector from the resulting data table.

Note that instead of listing the data elements on one line, they must be entered on separate lines.

```
aString <- "AAA 
BBB 
CCC 
DDD 
EEE 
FFF 
GGG 
HHH"
# use text argument to read the aString object as if it is an external file
aVector <- read.table(text=aString,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)$V1
aVector
```

...and the output:

```
> aVector
[1] "AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD" "EEE" "FFF" "GGG" "HHH"
>
```

This technique enables one to enter data in rows, and read it into a data frame.

```
# example with multiple vectors per row

aString ="
var1 var2
var1 var2
var1 var2"

read.table(text=aString,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

...and the output:

```
> read.table(text=aString,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    V1   V2
1 var1 var2
2 var1 var2
3 var1 var2
>
```

Comment: Looks truly useful for something else I wanted to automate. Nice method, thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the object as a character vector of length 1, ie

```
x <- "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH"
```

then  you can use `scan` to parse this into a character vector.

```
myVec <- scan(textConnection(x), what="", sep=",")
```

Since `scan` typically expects an external file, you can construct something that will work on the fly with `textConnection`. The inner workings of connections are still a bit blurry to me, but they can be very helpful when working with large files via chunking. See `?textConnection` and `?file` for more details on connections.

This returns your desired result.

```
myVec
[1] "AAA"  " BBB" " CCC" " DDD" " EEE" " FFF" " GGG" " HHH"
```